# Use AudioCard of Microsoft Bot with Microsoft Teams see bot UI shows "Go back to the main window to see this content."

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I can run this Teams Bot sample:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot

When I need to add an AudioCard to play a mp3 song, I updated my code:

```
    private async Task CardActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, bool update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var card = GetAudioCard();

        await SendUpdatedCardAudio(turnContext, card, cancellationToken);

    }

    private static AudioCard GetAudioCard()
    {
        var audioCard = new AudioCard
        {
            Title = "I am your father",
            Subtitle = "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
            Text = "The Empire Strikes Back (also known as Star Wars: Episode V – The Empire Strikes Back)" +
                   " is a 1980 American epic space opera film directed by Irvin Kershner. Leigh Brackett and" +
                   " Lawrence Kasdan wrote the screenplay, with George Lucas writing the film's story and serving" +
                   " as executive producer. The second installment in the original Star Wars trilogy, it was produced" +
                   " by Gary Kurtz for Lucasfilm Ltd. and stars Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, Billy Dee Williams," +
                   " Anthony Daniels, David Prowse, Kenny Baker, Peter Mayhew and Frank Oz.",
            Image = new ThumbnailUrl
            {
                Url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3c/SW_-_Empire_Strikes_Back.jpg",
            },
            Media = new List<MediaUrl>
            {
                new MediaUrl()
                {
                    Url = "https://wavlist.com/wav/father.wav",
                },
            },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Read More",
                    Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                    Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back",
                },
            },
        };

        return audioCard;
    }

    private static async Task SendUpdatedCardAudio(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, AudioCard card, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);

        reply.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Above modification is with reference from this sample:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards

When I tested it in Teams Bot, I see the following replies:
[From Teams Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHQhu.png)

The replies said: "Go back to the main window to see this content.".

Do you know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the "Bot Framework" is a general Bot creation framework from Microsoft, with Teams just being one particular implementation. As a result, some things are simply not supported in a Teams context. In this case, as per the docs over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#cards-not-supported-in-teams):

```
The following cards are implemented by the Bot Framework, but are not supported by Teams:

- ..
- Audio cards
- ..
```

So you would need to implement another solution to audio, unfortunately. What you could instead perhaps do is provide a link to the audio file, or to a player, something like that. Another alternative is to implement a Task Module (basically a popup in Teams) that embeds your own small html5 audio player.

So what ou

Comment: Hi Hilton, thank you for the information.
Though Task Module is not exact what I want, I had a try.

According to this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots?tabs=nodejs#example-of-taskfetch-and-tasksubmit-invoke-messages-in-nodejs-and-c

I set:
taskInfo.Url = taskInfo.FallbackUrl = "https://davyweb.chinacloudsites.cn/musicplayer/mainpage.html";

When the bot popped up the modal dialog, I didn't see my webpage inside it.

Do you know why?

Comment: When a page isn't appearing, it can be because you don't own the page (the page needs to be something you can modify, so as to insert a reference to the Teams JS module), but it also needs to be registered in the "validDomains" section in the manifest file, so Teams knows to trust the domain. See the schema for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Comment: Hi Hilton, I tried from local (use ngrok), and also deployed bot to Azure App Service. I added all the domains to validDomains:
  "validDomains": [ "*.ngrok.io",
                    "*.youtube.com",
                    "*.chinacloudsites.cn",
                    "sensitivebot.azurewebsites.net",
     "*.azurewebsites.net"]
Then installed the zip package to Teams as an App.
But I still can't see the default Youtube webpage in the official sample. (The Popup dialog is empty) 
If I open the url directly, I can see youtube webpage: https://sensitivebot.azurewebsites.net/youtube

Comment: Do you have further suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you use "." in front, like "youtube.com" instead of ".youtube.com", but in any case that's not your issue (you have "sensitivebot.azurewebsites.net" correctly). You can use wildcards, but then they must be "*". I seem to remember there might be an issue with needing another valid domain entry somewhere for this to work. It might be in the 'messageHandlers.value.domains' section in the manifest. If you can, try that out.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Hilton. But no luck. I found another sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp
After deployed, the issue was the same. But this sample has a demo Bot manifest. I deployed it and can call customeform successfully. My manifest and this one are almost same except AppID and AppServiceName. Don't know why. Might be Bot configurations? I switched on Diagnostic logs, see if there will be evidences in it.

Comment: Hi Hilton, I found the solution. I created the Bot before from the resource "Azure Bot". I deleted it, then created a "Bot Channels Registration", then it works. But from Portal, this resource looks going to be deprecated. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: ok glad you came right! What are you seeing that makes it look to be deprecated?

Comment: Hilton, If you try to create a "Bot Channels Registration" from Portal, you'll see following words: "This resource will be deprecated on 9/1/2021. Please use Bot Service’s new Azure Bot resource." in Overview.

Comment: ahh ok, I see what you mean - I haven't created a new one for a little while so didn't see that. It looks like it's just being converted over to "Azure Bot", and it doesn't look like there's any different function. It might just be a naming change ("Bot Channels Registration" was a bit confusing, especially when building a Teams bot where "Channel" means something else entirely. Thanks for letting me know about this!